# Why do Hobbs and Toretto stand side by side during the final scene?

Tags: fast-and-furious-franchise, fast-and-furious-6, blocking

In the final scene of Furious 6 (aka The Fast and the Furious 6) Hobbs (Dwayne The Rock Johnson) and Toretto (Vin Diesel) enjoy a private moment where they awkwardly say thank you and express some mutual respect. The blocking (where they're standing) in this scene seems quite intentional but very weird. The two muscle bound stars don't face each other, they stand along side each other but facing in opposite directions.

This gives the scene a super awkward feeling, plus creates a weird optical illusion in certain shots whereby Hobbs looks tiny (or badly green screened in)

[image]

Can anyone explain the logic, meaning, or reasoning for this 
odd blocking moment in an otherwise flawless movie? :)

Comment: lol for 'otherwise flawless movie'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you try and force the north ends of two bar magnets together, a comfortable ending position looks sort of like this. The same ends of a magnet don't really like facing each other.  This is what this scene reminded me of.

They're two tough guys, both doing things the way they want to, but they're opposites, and they clash.

Standing like this and looking past each other is non-confrontational; because they can't look into each other's eyes, it avoids the temptation to dominate each other, and both can walk away as equals.  They're also not going to shake hands, hug, or chug beers together.

It's an uneasy truce.

Comment: This was my feeling too.  It wouldn't feel right for these two characters to stare into each other's eyes, that's usually reserved for either a confrontation or a "tender moment".  This was neither.  By sort of looking over each other's shoulders, they can retain their tough appearance, and yet acknowledge each other.  Yet, I can't get over the thought that this was also meant to make Torreto look bigger than usual, because as huge as he looks when he's onscreen by himself, he's dwarfed by Hobbs.

Comment: But it looks so crap, who signed off on this?!?